# Unable to connect to thin server on ubuntu

Tags: linux, webserver, amazon-ec2

I'm unable to connect to my webserver over the web.

I've got an ec2 instance running with ubuntu 11.10 on it. It's running a thin server on port 9292. I can ssh into the ec2 box, and do curl localhost:9292 - this returns content, so thin is definitely running.

I've opened up port 9292 in my ec2 security group, so I wouldn't think that amazon is stopping the connection.

Do I need to set something else up on the ubuntu box? I'm also running thin under a user who doesn't have sudo access.

If you can help I'd be very grateful!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked firewall rules on the Ubuntu box?  If you're not familiar with working with iptables then [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) may give you enough of a starting point.

Comment: Thanks, I had a look and it seems that all traffic is enabled by default (and I'm connected via ssh) - I've also run something like sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9292 -j ACCEPT, and it all looks fine from that end.

My output from sudo iptables -L is:
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:9292